# SQLAlchemy failing to close connections to Postgresql data base

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

I've been stuck on this for quite sometime.  Currently I have a Flask app that communicates to a Postgresql database.  My issue is that after I'm done communicating to the database sqlalchemy keeps the connection open.  It does this until eventually I reach my max allowed connections and the postgresql database fails.  I've turned off pooling and still am having the issue here's my database code below:

```
class Database():
    def __init__(self):
        #Connect to the database, currently using default settings
        self.con = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url_postgres, client_encoding='utf8', poolclass=NullPool)

        #Bind the connection ot MetaData()
        self.meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData(bind=self.con, reflect=True)

        #Get a session going
        Session = sessionmaker()
        Session.configure(bind=self.con)
        self.session = Session() 

        if 'users' not in self.meta.tables:
            users = Table('users', self.meta,
                Column('username', String(50), unique=True, nullable=False, primary_key=True),
                Column('password', Text, nullable=False),
                Column('name', String(50)),
                Column('salt', Text, nullable=False))

            self.meta.create_all(self.con)

        if 'matchups' not in self.meta.tables:
            users = self.meta.tables['users'] 
            matchups = Table('matchups', self.meta,
               Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                Column('team_one', String(50), ForeignKey("users.username"), nullable=False), 
                Column('team_one_score', Float, nullable=False),
                Column('team_two', String(50), ForeignKey('users.username'), nullable=False), 
                Column('team_two_score', Float, nullable=False),
                Column('year', Integer, nullable=False),
                Column('week', Integer, nullable=False))

           self.meta.create_all(self.con)

   def close(self):
        self.con.dispose()
```

I call the following and a couple member from the class like so:

```
db = Database()
user = db.getUser(player)
history = sortTeamHistory(player) 
users = db.getUsers()
db.close()
```

But when I check my open connections on my postgresql database there are still some open.
I know the issue is with the python flask app since if I restart the program the connections are closed.
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you close your session anywhere? `Engine.dispose()` only closes connections that are still in the pool, not the connections that are still in use by live sessions. Normally you would only have a single engine globally and you wouldn't dispose of the engine during the lifetime of your app; you would only close each session so that you benefit from connection pooling.